# time complexity of nested for loop with j<=i condition

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I had this question on a assignment.

Determine the time-complexity of the nested loop

```
for(int i=1; i<=n; i=2*i){
    for(int j=1; j<=i; i=2*j){
        stuff
    }
}
```

I understand that with i and j being incremented by 2x that the complexity would be something along the lines of log2(n) * log2(n), but with the inner loop running to i rather than n I'm completely lost

I need to know the complexity of the nested loop and a step-by-step on how it was solved.

Comment: Should `i=2*j` be `j=2*j`?

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop runs `log(i) + 1` times (log base 2).

Adding the outer-loop, sum the above for `i = 1, 2, 4, ... n`.

So: `(log(1) + 1) + (log(2) + 1) + (log(4) + 1) + ... + (log(n) + 1)`

which is: `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + log(n)`

using the sum of arithmetic series is: `(log(n) + 1) * (log(n) + 2) / 2 = (log(n)*log(n) + 3log(n) + 2) / 2 = O(log(n) * log(n))`

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume n=16 for example, so i will have values `i = 1, 2, 4, 8, 16`.

So: i is basically taking value as log(n) i.e log(16) i.e five iterations.

now for the value of j, it's taking value as `log(1) + log(2) + log(4) + log(8) + log(16)`. It's basically equal to log(i) in each iteration.

So combining the values we got from the above two statements, we can say the time-complexity of the above code is `O(log(n) * log(i))`.

This is my understanding about the code.